# Unix - How can I resolve :command not found

Tags: unix

I have 2 scripts test1.sh & test2.sh, below is the defn. for the same

cat test1.sh

```
DUP_CHK=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select count(*) from table1"`

echo "$DUP_CHK"
export DUP_CHK
```

cat test2.sh

```
#!/bin/bash


source ./test1.sh

cnt_chk="$DUP_CHK"
cnt_chk_2=`beeline --showHeader=false --outputformat=tsv2 -e "select count(*) from table1"`

echo "$DUP_CHK"
echo "$cnt_chk"
echo "$cnt_chk_2"

if "$cnt_chk -eq $cnt_chk_2"
     then
       echo "You are right"
       exit 0
else
    echo "Something is not right, check"
    exit  0
fi
```

I am passing both value as same but, the error throws as
`test2.sh: line 18: 100 -eq 100: command not found`

What am I missing here. Thoughts?? Thanks.

Comment: `if "$cnt_chk -eq $cnt_chk_2"`  is trying to execute the command "100 -eq 100"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need

```
  if((cnt_chk == cnt_chk2))
```

Comment: Yup, this worked, I should have looked at brackets once... :) Thanks...